# Setting parts of a positive semidefinite matrix to zeros, still be positive semidefinite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I come across a problem.
$$
M = \left[\begin{array}{c}
A_{3 \times 7} \\
B_{4 \times 7}
\end{array}\right]_{7 \times7}
$$

is a positive semidefinite matrix.

If we set the lower matrix $B_{4 \times 7}$ to all zeros, such that
$$
M_{new} = \left[\begin{array}{c}
A_{3 \times 7} \\
O_{4 \times 7}
\end{array}\right]_{7 \times7}
$$

Will this new matrix be a positive semidefinite matrix?

Comment: I assume you're working over $\mathbb R$.  The answer is yes *iff* columns 4-7 of $A$ are all zero.  *Exercise:*  prove that if a matrix $M$ is real symmetric PSD and has a zero in component $m_{k,k}$, then all of column k and row k are zero.